# Opencart echo values out of loop

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I have inherited a hacked Opencart theme. There is a fully functioning owl carousel on the home page that echos a loop of products. All works well except it wont echo the following:

```
<?php echo $product['model']; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $product['tax']; ?>
```

The other details like name, price after tax, etc but i can't for the life of me work out how to echo these two. I think its very likely that the correct controllers weren't setup.

Is it possible to grab the product ID then echo these values, inside the loop.

Quite easy in WP but OC is a different beast.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: try `var_dump($product)` to see what's in there

Comment: What is a "hacked Opencart theme"? It sounds suspiciously like we shouldn't help you with anything related to it.

Comment: var_dump is outputting tax as 0.00 which is wrong. When i say hacked - it was bought by the previous developer but messed up and i'm trying to fix it.

Comment: And model isn't coming through in the var_dump at all.

Answer (score 0):

I took a step back from this and just calculated the value based on the price i could get. Quite easy when working out VAT.

Answer (score 0):

With 99% probability these two parameters should be defined in controller of the module. Try to find it in

/catalog/controller/extension/module/your_carusel_module_name.php

find something like

```
        $data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'       => $image,
            'name'        => $result['name'],
```

and after it

```
'model'        => $result['model'],
'tax'         => $tax,
```

and before $data['products'][] = array(

```
        if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
            $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
        } else {
            $tax = false;
        }
```

For more correct answer - post code of controller in your question.